# AVPlayer controls display "live" and wrong duration while playing Sliding window HLS stream

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

The problem is with playing a HLS stream with a 2 hour sliding window.

After playing starts the duration time keeps counting up from 2 hours and onwards. After 2 hours the duration displays 4 hours but when seeking from start the seekbar jumps to the middle of the bar since the stream is only 2 hours long.

When seeking the current time stamp displays "live".

Master playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1790579110,BANDWIDTH=128000
live/stream1.m3u8
```

stream1.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:13148
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-VERSION:2
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXTINF:8,
../../../../hls-live/streams/ruv-ras1/events/_definst_/live/stream1Num13148.ts
#EXTINF:8,
../../../../hls-live/streams/ruv-ras1/events/_definst_/live/stream1Num13149.ts
#EXTINF:8,
../../../../hls-live/streams/ruv-ras1/events/_definst_/live/stream1Num13150.ts
#EXTINF:8,
../../../../hls-live/streams/ruv-ras1/events/_definst_/live/stream1Num13151.ts
#EXTINF:8,
../../../../hls-live/streams/ruv-ras1/events/_definst_/live/stream1Num13152.ts
#EXTINF:8,
../../../../hls-live/streams/ruv-ras1/events/_definst_/live/stream1Num13153.ts
#EXTINF:8,
../../../../hls-live/streams/ruv-ras1/events/_definst_/live/stream1Num13154.ts
```

While seeking the "current time" should preferably display where in the stream you are scrubbing but not "Live".

And the duration should stay within the Sliding window and not allow you to scrub back 4 hours.

Comment: How did you solve this problem with your playlist?